# How to remove everything behind the empty space?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how can I delete everything that is behind an empty space. I have a date like: 10.10.2010 18:34 with an empty space between the year and the 18. I only need the first part of the string (only 10.10.2010). So I tried to use preg_replace to remove everything behind the empty space, but it doesnt work. How would my expression have to be?

Thank you for your help!
phpheini

Comment: Why regexp? A `split` would be way more efficient. Or even findChar and then `substring`, even more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your simple requirements, rather than going with a full regex solution, you can simply tokenize the string using [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

```
$datePart = strtok($dateString, ' ');
```

**Edit:** The only reason I could see to involve regular expressions would be to validate the date-time string at the same time as extracting parts. For example

```
if (preg_match('/(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}) (\d{1,2}:\d{2})/', $dateTimeString, $parts)) {
    $date = $parts[1];
    $time = $parts[2];
} else {
    throw new Exception('Invalid date-time string format');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident of the formatting:

```
$date = strstr('10.10.2010 18:34', ' ', true); // requires PHP 5.3.0 or greater
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '10.10.2010 18:34';

$str = preg_replace('/\s.*?$/', '', $str);

var_dump($str); // string(10) "10.10.2010"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/bTtFEQfv).

As [Phil Brown states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036616/how-to-remove-everything-behind-the-empty-space/5036642#5036642), however, using something like `strtok()` is much better for a simple task like this (compare the answers and it is obvious).